# postgresql and subqueries as columns (duplicate rows)

Tags: postgresql

I am having some issue with a postgresql query using subqueries as columns.  I am not a DBA as I usually rely on an ORM to handle my db stuff so bear with me.....  Here are my abbreviated table definitions:

```
\d profile
                                           Table "public.profile"
          Column           |           Type           |                      Modifiers
---------------------------+--------------------------+------------------------------------------------------
 id                        | integer                  | not null default nextval('profile_id_seq'::regclass)
 _tracking_number_obj_id   | integer

\d trackingnumber;
                                     Table "public.trackingnumber"
     Column      |         Type          |                          Modifiers
-----------------+-----------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------
 id              | integer               | not null default nextval('trackingnumber_id_seq'::regclass)
 tracking_number | character varying(16) | not null

 \d dd;
                                    Table "public.dd"
     Column     |         Type          |                         Modifiers
----------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------
 id             | integer               | not null default nextval('dd_id_seq'::regclass)
 created_date   | date                  | not null
 completed      | boolean               | not null
 completed_date | date                  |
 type           | character varying(10) | not null
 profile_id     | integer               | not null
```

My query I am trying:

```
select tn.tracking_number,
last_c,
last_l
from 
trackingnumber as tn, profile as p, dd as dd,
(select max(completed_date) from dd as dd, profile as p where profile_id = p.id and type='C') as last_c,
(select max(completed_date) from dd as dd, profile as p where profile_id = p.id and type='L') last_l
where p._tracking_number_obj_id = tn.id and dd.profile_id = p.id;
```

The expect result would be one  row per p.id, but I am getting one row for every row in the dd table.

Example:

```
select count(*) from dd;
 count
-------
    10
```

Results of the above query:

```
tracking_number | last_c  |  last_l
-----------------+--------------+--------------
 5004            | (2019-10-23) | (2019-10-23)
 5004            | (2019-10-23) | (2019-10-23)
 5004            | (2019-10-23) | (2019-10-23)
 5004            | (2019-10-23) | (2019-10-23)
 5004            | (2019-10-23) | (2019-10-23)
 5004            | (2019-10-23) | (2019-10-23)
 5004            | (2019-10-23) | (2019-10-23)
 5003            | (2019-10-23) | (2019-10-23)
 5003            | (2019-10-23) | (2019-10-23)
 5003            | (2019-10-23) | (2019-10-23)
```

What the desired result is:

```
tracking_number | last_c  |  last_l
-----------------+--------------+--------------
 5004            | (2019-10-23) | (2019-10-23)
 5003            | (2019-10-23) | (2019-10-23)
```

Comment: can't you use 'distinct'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the join with `dd` is unnecessary.

Try removing

```
dd as dd,
```

and

```
and dd.profile_id = p.id
```

from the query and see if you like the result better.